# Converting LinqToExcel.RowNoHeader type into string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-excel

I have been using LinqToExcel Library Lately and i came across this issue.

here is the code

```
  var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(fileName);
  var dataList = (from c in excel.WorksheetRangeNoHeader("A1", "A4", "Test Worksheet")
                select c).ToList();
```

This dataList Collection Will have something like "Cat","Dog" ,"Fish" and "Goat"

Now All i want to do is assign Fish to a variable as an string by doing something like this

```
string temp=dataList[2];
```

However when i run the code i get the value of temp as "LinqToExcel.RowNoHeader". Anyone got idea on how to extract the actual value Fish into the variable temp.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you put a break point before `string temp=dataList[2];` can you tree the object out in the locals window to see what property is holding the value?

Comment: There is no such properties. However in the debugger window i see something like this _items=LinqToExcel.RowNoHeader[4]; This is what holds the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cracked it !
I was referring to the whole row rather than the first cell of each row.
Therefore i needed C[0] in order to get the items.

```
 var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(fileName);
 var dataList = (from c in excel.WorksheetRangeNoHeader("A1", "A4", "Test Worksheet")
            select c[0]).ToList();
```

And the extraction code will be

```
var temp=Convert.ToString(dataList[2]);
```